# Codeigniter : Redirect to homepage after session expiration

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Is there any ways that I can used to redirect to homepage after session expiration using config.php file?

Currently I'm using this code in every views files:

```
<?php if (!$this->simpleloginsecure->is_signed_in()) 
    { 
redirect ('main');

}else{ 

/*here is the code in views file */

} ?>
```

I need to put it in every views file so if there is any other way, I would like to know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add more code. E.g. your session controller/model functions.

Comment: I didn't found any related code from controller/model. This is from libraries: 

`function is_signed_in()
{
$this->CI =& get_instance();
$row = $this->CI->db->get_where('users',array('user_id'=>$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id')))->row();
if(isset($row->user_id))
return true;
else
return false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can manage routing in controller 
you should set predefined function in codeigniter which is "_remap"
as this example:

```
function _remap($functionName){if (logging()){ /**here should define  functions for logged users*/}else{ /*here should define functions for others**/}}
```

in this way you check user privileges once :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check session in config file

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('session_name')) 
{ 
   redirect ('main');
}
```